# How to call php function from button?

Tags: php

I've got an easy php script :

```
<?php
    $command = "git pull";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And I want to call it by pressing button :

```
<form metod="post" action="/pull.php">
   <button type="submit">Pull changes</button>
</form>
```

And I want to get output right under the button or replace button with output but I don't want to go to /pull.php I just want to run script and get output. How can I make it ?

Comment: You can't do this just with php, you will need to use AJAX. Javascript calling the php.

Comment: @fb1: "Javascript asking the remote webserver to call the PHP" for clarity wins.

Comment: Get yourself a book on AJAX. This is _far_ too broad a question to answer any further than that.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, that is much clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use javascript's XMLHTTPRequest (or better yet [jQuery's get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)), in either case JavaScript will let you load content dynamically from another url.

Answer (score 1):

To use ajax to get the response and display it below the button, first make space for the message below the button:

```
 <form onclick='run()'>
 <button type="submit">Pull changes</button>
 <div id='msg'><div/>
 </form>
```

now in the header tag add the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function run()
 {
 loadXMLDoc("pull.php",function()
 {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('msg') = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 });
 }
 function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
 {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
 xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Additions: `return run()` and `return false;`; sane indentation; explanation rather than naive code-dump; a framework.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language and clicking a button is a client-side action, thus you'll need to use a client-side solution like JavaScript to bridge the gap.

Answer (score -1):

leave the action property empty and put that code right after the button, you'll have something like:

```
<form metod="post" action="">
    <button name="button" type="submit">Pull changes</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $command = "git pull";
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Still performs a full form submission. My interpretation is that the OP wants to use the "new hotness" that is _inline form submission_.